# No matching function for call to "qsort"

Tags: c++, qsort

I can't seem to get qsort to work in my problem. I look around online and my code should be correct.

```
int file::compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
     fileinfo* fa = (fileinfo*)a;
     fileinfo* fb = (fileinfo*)b;
     return (*(int*)fa->inode - *(int*)fb->inode);
}

void file::print()
{
    qsort((void *)files, 100, sizeof(fileinfo), compare);
}
```

`files` is an array of fileinfo. `struct fileinfo` is a struct that contains the name and inode of a file.

Comment: Why are you using `qsort` in C++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`file::compare` must be declared `static` to be used as a parameter to `qsort`.